# FAKE patterns to separate target build order from dependencies

Tags: f#-fake, f#-fake-4

In VS there is usually a distinction between Build (incremental) and Rebuild, where the latter would first clean but then do the same as Build. Can I provide similar behavior with FAKE?

Let's assume the following targets:

```
Target "Clean" DoNothing
Target "Work" DoNothing
Target "All" DoNothing

RunTargetOrDefault "All"
```

Normally I want to run all of them, Clean before Work, so I end up with:

```
"Clean" ==> "Work" ==> "All"
```

However, Work is not really depending on Clean - it is only that if both are to be run, Clean must run first. With the dependency chain above, I cannot run Work without Clean being run first. Is there way or common pattern to support this?

What I've considered so far:

A)

```
"Clean" ==> "All"
"Work" ==> "All"
```

This correctly represents the dependencies from All, but the order that Clean should be before Work - if both are run - is missing.

B)

```
Target "WorkOnly" DoNothing
"WorkOnly" ==> "Work"
"Clean" ==> "Work" ==> "All"
```

This is a bit closer, but it still does not guarantee that when building All that Clean will run before WorkOnly

C)

```
Target "Start" DoNothing
"Start"
  =?> ("Clean", not (hasBuildParam "noclean"))
  ==> "Work"
  ==> "All"
```

This way, Clean would always run, except when I specify "noclean" as parameter.
This seems to fully support my scenario and is actually quite flexible, but can get a bit complicated if there are multiple optional phases.

Is this the intended way and how others do it as well, or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no operator for this at the moment. You might want to create a pull request with a new operator.

We also have a [prototype implementation](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/b80c364fee1eef454afc4b7e1aa064a6c567d011/src/app/FakeLib/Targets.fsx) for a future target dependency runtime. You can also try to add a new operator there.

Comment: Thanks - I'll think about a few options and then join in

Comment: we now have support for "soft dependencies" - see http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/soft-dependencies.html

Answer (score 9):

I'm a bit late to the party.... But I've recently run into this kind of requirement myself.

I finally settled on the following:

- All tasks are independent
- Create multiple end state targets that define different dependencies.

In your case that would leave you with

```
Target "Clean" DoNothing
Target "Work" DoNothing
Target "Build" (fun _ ->
    Run "Work"
)
Target "Rebuild" (fun _ ->
    "Clean"
        ==> "Work"

    Run "Work"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late here but this might help someone.  You can use soft dependencies like so (substitute "Work" for "Build" if you like):

```
// read 'x ==> y ' as "x runs before y"
"Build" ==> "All"
"Clean" ==> "All"
"Clean" ?=> "Build" // Soft dependency: Correct order when multi-threading?
"All" ==> "Deploy"
```

Alternatively I prefer the `<==` operator.

```
// read 'x <== ys' as "x depends on ys" like traditional make rules
"Build"  <=? "Clean"  
"All"    <== ["Clean"; "Build"]
"Deploy" <== ["All"]
```